# OCUnit example on iOS for Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, ocunit

I already created a App that use OCUnit and it run these tests with Xcode 3.2. However, today I upgrade to Xcode 4 and I also create new project, add bundle,...but I can't run test cases.
The build always show: "Suceeded"

Can you tell me a tutorial do this step-by-step?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4, test cases are more tightly integrated with the IDE.

When you create a project, check the "Include Unit Tests" checkbox in the project setup dialog, which will add the necessary frameworks.

To actually run the tests, just select "Test" from the Product menu instead of "Build" or "Run".